# Eclipse syntax coloring makes my code illegible

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

What exactly is Eclipse doing here to the symbol `CreateDefaultSource`?

[image]

If I single-click a symbol and hover over it for a short while, it shades the background to an illegible light-grey. Clicking off of the symbol doesn't immediately cause it to go away.

I'm using the [Color Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) plugin to provide syntax coloring. I thought perhaps this was the "Content Assist" background color, but I've changed that under the general prefs and I'm still getting this.

And perhaps a slightly more egregious example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to bluish's hint, I found the appropriate settings to modify these colors:

- For references: `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > PHP elements 'read' occurrences`
- For assignment lvalues: `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > PHP elements 'write' occurrences`

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this behaviour: in Preferences search for Mark occurences. You will find some sections, each one for a programming language (Java, Javascript, Python,..). Uncheck this option:

> Keep marks when the selection changes